# Can we create a Modern webpart to use as a List or Library form for all the lists/Libraries in SharePoint?(SPFX or Powerapp)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, web-part, office-365, spfx

Can we create solution to use a web part as list form for all Lists and Libraries?

We should have select the List/Library name accordingly the fields should be loaded to submit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SharePoint out of the box web part using which you can achieve your requirements.

But you can develop such web part using [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) in SharePoint online.

There is a similar web part created by community members. You can download the source code from below link & enhance it as per your requirements:

[List Form web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-list-form)

Comment: Hi @srinivas, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Ofcourse yes. Basically you have to define the logic in such a way that based on the type of the field you need to render the control. You can use Office fabric UI controls to have same look and feel as we get in SP online forms. List Form Web part shared by @Ganesh is one of the best example.